# possible firefox go to internet but chrome and IE not?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, troubleshooting

my Firefox go to internet correctly. but IE and chrome don't see the internet. my windows is 7 and i check the proxy in windows ...

before when i have similar to this error check the proxy settings... but now ... i dont know what shoot this trouble ;)

[image: proxy internet explorer and windows]

```
my IE version is 9.0.8

fire fox is version 17

chrome is 24
```

[image: Firefox setting]

Comment: Does Firefox stop working if you select "Use system proxy settings"?

Comment: Have you tried to update both Chrome and Firefox to the current version?

Comment: @georgefox not related to proxy.

Comment: @Ramhound updated